# What is the difference between two 'char*' castings in c++

Tags: c++, c, casting, constants

I do have a "C" function

```
find_register(char *name)
```

which is called from a "C++" routine. The first tip to call it was

```
find_register("%ebx")
```

It results in a warning

```
deprecated conversion from string constant to 'char*'
```

OK, I corrected it to

```
find_register(string("%ebx").c_str())
```

which results in the error message

```
"invalid conversion from 'const char*' to 'char*'
```

Finally,

```
find_register((char*)string("%ebx").c_str())
```

is accepted without error message and warnings.

My questions: 
1./ The probable reason of the error message is that the possibility of changing a 'const char*' is left open. It is OK, but in the first case the less sophisticated version allows the same, and converting a string constant to 'char *' is a legal, but deprecated conversion. Is there any deeper reason behind?

2./ Is there any simple method to do what I want? (the perfect (for the compiler) code is hardly readable for the programmer)

Comment: You want to input a variable, `find_register(char *name)` is ok. But you input a text, its not ok

Comment: `find_register(string("%ebx").c_str())` was not "correcting it", it was just making the problem worse.

Comment: I assume you don't want to change the register names you are using as a find key in the find_register function - So why don't you tell the compiler? Declare the function so that it takes a "const char *"

Comment: @  tofro You are absolutely right, but I am calling in my app a 3rd-party function with a third-party string array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The prototype for the function `find_register(char*)` indicates that it may change the parameter since it is just a pointer that is passed. You do not mention if you have the source code of that function so I assume you don't otherwise it would be better to change that function to accept a `char const *` provided it doesn't change the contents.

Otherwise just pass a modifiable array:

```
char arg[] = "%ebx";
find_register(arg);
```

to write:

```
find_register((char*)string("%ebx").c_str())
```

is dangerous, what if the function does indeed modify the string e.g. `strtok`? But if you insist at least try to use the C++ style of casting instead of C casting (in this case `find_register(const_cast<char*>("%ebx"))`).

**Side note**: personally I find it easier to read to avoid using the C-way of putting const when possible. So instead of writing `const char *` write `char const  *` and `char * const` when the pointer is constant i.e. const always goes to the left - it is more consistent.

Comment: I am pretty sure (in this case) it is not dangerous, since the function makes only a table lookup. Concerning side note: the consistency and readability is important, but leads to the question :the '*' belongs to what? (say, what declares 'char* a,b;' or 'char *a,b;')

Comment: @katang i prefer to write one declaration on each line and put the ptr symbol close to the type since I find it a part of the type. IMHO it makes the code a little bit clearer and less prone to oops :-) e.g. `char* a; char b;` but it is just my personal preference. const on the right side also works better with typedef.

Answer (score 11):

The reasoning lies in the original roots of C++ language, back in the time when certain amount of backward compatibility with C was considered important.

In C language string literals, despite being non-modifiable, have type `char [N]`. For this reason they are implicitly convertible to type `char *` in C. In C++ string literals have type `const char[N]`. Formally, `const char[N]` is not implicitly convertible to `char *`. But for aforementioned C compatibility reasons the original C++ specification (C++98) allowed implicit conversion of string literals to `char *`. This exception was made for immediate string literals only, as a form of special treatment provided to string literals.

But eventually the matter of C compatibility became unimportant and this special treatment was deprecated in C++03. So, this is what the compiler is telling you. In your `find_register("%ebx")` call it agrees to convert the immediate string literal to `char *`, but warns you that this conversion is deprecated. In C++11 this implicit conversion is outlawed entirely.

In all other contexts (not an immediate string literal), implicit conversion of `const char [N]` or `const char *` to `char *` is prohibited and has always been prohibited. This is why your

```
find_register(string("%ebx").c_str())`
```

variant has no chance of compiling.

As for working around this restriction... If you are sure that `find_register(char *name)` does not attempt to change the data pointed by `name` (and you cannot just change the `find_register`'s parameter type to `const char *name`), then

```
find_register(const_cast<char *>("%ebx"))
```

is a fairly acceptable solution (with an appropriate accompanying comment). Of course, if `find_register` is a modifying function, then you'll have to do something like

```
char reg[] = "%ebx";
find_register(reg);
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. Actually, I am using 3rd-party code, and adapting it for C++. So, actually both "%ebx" and "find_register(char *name)" are "foreign" for me, and I need to use them from C++. Your suggestion for using 'const_cast<char *>("%ebx")' is optically appealing for me.

Answer (score 1):

If you are passing string literals to `find_register(char *name)`, then the function prototype should be `find_register(const char *name)`, as string literals are not modifiable.

With this conversion, C++ will happily let you shoot yourself in the foot and try to modify `name`, which gives me a segmentation fault, as in the following code:

```
void modifyIllegally(char* name) {
    name[0]='d';
}

int main() {
    modifyIllegally("abc");
}
```

Edit: If you don't control the API of the C program and are sure it won't change the `char*`, you can disable this warning with compiler flags. For gcc the flag is `-Wno-write-strings`.

Comment: OK, as I wrote, I understand this possibility. My question was about why C++ compiler handles differently those essentially identical cases.

Comment: @katang The point is that they are very not identical: a string literal is internally unmodifiable: it's decided at compile time and cannot be changed. Initializing a `char*` in this way works for backwards-compatibility reasons, but it's inherently unsafe, so the compiler warns you about it. C never let you implicitly convert a `const char*` to a `char*` in other ways, and so the compiler doesn't even bother warning you: it just forbids it.